# Alfresco web service get all users under site

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm new to `alfresco`.

Using `web services with java`, I am connecting to Alfresco. Now I want all the users under group.

Please let me know if any.

For getting sub-folder, I am using `Lucena query` like this:

```
String luceneQuery = "PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:lntlegal/cm:" + strRootFolder + "/*\" AND TYPE:\"cm:folder\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Each site of Alfresco Share is linked to a user group. This group contains the user list and their roles.

The main group is named `GROUP_site_` + siteUrl. It contains 4 subgroup, one for each role : SiteManager, SiteCollaborator, SiteContributor and SiteConsumer.

Their type is "cm:authorityContainer".

If your site has for URL name "lntlegal", its groups will be:

```
GROUP_site_lntlegal
|- GROUP_site_lntlegal_SiteManager
|- GROUP_site_lntlegal_SiteCollaborator
|- GROUP_site_lntlegal_SiteContributor
|- GROUP_site_lntlegal_SiteConsumer
```

You can retrieve a group with the following Lucene query:

```
@cm\:authorityName:"GROUP_site_lntlegal_SiteConsumer"
```

The users are the children of the association "cm:member".

Here is a sample code to do this using the Web Service API:

```
final String site = "lntlegal";

for(final String role : Arrays.asList("SiteManager", "SiteCollaborator", "SiteContributor", "SiteConsumer")) {
    String luceneQuery = "@cm\\:authorityName:\"GROUP_site_" + site + '_' + role + "\"";
    Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, luceneQuery);

    QueryResult queryResult = repositoryService.query(store, query, true);
    ResultSet resultSet = queryResult.getResultSet();
    ResultSetRow[] rows = resultSet.getRows();

    ResultSetRowNode node = rows[0].getNode();
    Reference reference = new Reference(store, node.getId(), null);

    QueryResult associationQueryResult = repositoryService.queryChildren(reference); 
    ResultSet associationResultSet = associationQueryResult.getResultSet();
    ResultSetRow[] associationRows = associationResultSet.getRows();

    if(associationRows != null) {
        final String userNameQName = createQNameString(NAMESPACE_CONTENT_MODEL, "userName");
        for(final ResultSetRow row : associationRows) {
            String name = null;
            for(NamedValue value:row.getColumns()) {
                if(value.getName().equals(userNameQName)) {
                    name = value.getValue();
                }
            }

            System.out.println(row.getNode().getId() + " : " + name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SiteService.listMembers
```

will do the job ...but not 100% sure if the SiteService is available as SOAP WebService

If you'd like to get members of a group, then take a look at
`AuthorityService.getContainedAuthorities`